# Доступ к MySQL через SSH туннель

Tags: mysqli, php, ssh

Всем привет. Понадобилось подконнектиться к серверу MySQL через SSH туннель. (Вообще удивлен, что такое возможно, только узнал=))

Погуглил и нашел вот что:

```
    $connection = ssh2_connect($this->host, 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->user, $this->sshPass);
    $tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, $this->host, 3306);
```

Расширение ssh2 поставил, доступы инициализированы в классе. Туннель создан. Все хорошо. А дальше то что писать? Многие делают так:

```
    $this->db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname, 3306, $tunnel);
```

Но mysqli ругается на $tunnel, ибо ему нужна строковая переменная, а не ресурс.

Подскажите, что делать дальше? Всем добра

Comment: лучше тоннель на постоянку открой из скрипта отдельного handshake ssh очень медленная штука.